# JQuery Show Class on hover issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a div to show when a link is hovered.

There will be multiple classes too so only the nearest should show.

This is what I'm trying:

```
$(".box").hover(function() {
    $('.overlay').closest.show();
});

<div class="event" id="selector">                                       
    <a class="box" href="#" title="">Event</a>      
    <div class="overlayOuter">    
        <div class="overlayInner"></div>    
    </div>    
    <div class="overlay" style="display:none;"> I will come out when class Box is covered 
    </div>    
</div>
```

When I hover `class="box"` then `class="overlay"` is shown.

The problem is that Overlay is not appearing so I'm guessing my jquery is wrong?

How can I get this to work?

Comment: As a side point, your call to [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is all wrong. this should be `closest('selector')` not just `closest`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, overlay is not a parent it is a sibling, closest() gets the closest parent

```
   $(this).siblings('.overlay').show();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(this).siblings('.overlay').show();
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to use .siblings() because the `overlay` is not a ancestor element, it is a sibling element

```
$(".box").hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.overlay').show()
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In the current case `overlay` is a sibling, `closest` gets the closest parent.

[**Closest**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its
>   ancestors in the DOM tree.

[**Siblings**](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

> Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements,
>   optionally filtered by a selector.

Code:

```
$(".box").hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.overlay').show();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/tJr2e/